# Reading lines from a text file, converting them, then writing back to new file

Tags: c#, binary

I have some basic knowledge of C#, but I am having trouble coding something that seems simple in concept. I want to read a file (.asm) containing values such as

```
@1
@12
@96
@2
@46
etc.
```

on multiple consecutive lines. I then want to get rid of the @ symbols (if they are present), convert the remaining number values to binary, then write these binary values back to a new file (.hack) on their own lines. There isn't a set limit on the number of lines, which is my biggest issue as I don't know how to check for lines dynamically. So far I can only read and convert lines if I code to look for them, then I can't figure out how to write these values on their own lines in the new file. Sorry if this sounds a bit convoluted, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var line = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("testCode.hack"))
            {
                var str = line;
                var charsToRemove = new string[] {"@"};
                foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
                {
                    str = str.Replace(c, string.Empty);
                }
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(str);
                string value2 = Convert.ToString(value, 2);

                if (value2.Length < 16)
                {
                    int zeroes = 16 - value2.Length;
                    if(zeroes == 12)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("000000000000" + value2);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(value2);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you supply some code that you have already tried?

Comment: You might start here [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I added some of my code, but right now it only reads, converts and writes one line in the file, and doesn't handle more than one value at a time.

Comment: I would convert from ASCII to a hex array. Remove any value of @ in hex, then separate. I'd also look into using some regular expressions if you want to go line by line dynamically.

Comment: Also, I've tried to implement File.ReadAllLines, but I'm not sure the correct way to save all that it reads in a way that can be easily converted. Could that be done in an array or a list of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should help you get going real fast:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line = string.Empty;
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt");
        System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test.hack");
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) // Read until there is nothing more to read
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("@"))
            {
                line = line.Remove(0, 1); // Remove '@'
            }

            int value = -1;
            if (Int32.TryParse(line, out value)) // Check if the rest string is an integer
            {
                // Convert the rest string to its binary representation and write it to the file
                writer.WriteLine(intToBinary(value));
            }
            else
            {
                // Couldn't convert the string to an integer..
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        writer.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.Read();
    }

    //http://www.dotnetperls.com/binary-representation
    static string intToBinary(int n)
    {
        char[] b = new char[32];
        int pos = 31;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < 32)
        {
            if ((n & (1 << i)) != 0)
            {
                b[pos] = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                b[pos] = '0';
            }
            pos--;
            i++;
        }
        return new string(b);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This did exactly what I needed, and I'll use it to build off of as I extend the project.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion create a `List<string>`. Here are steps

1. Read input (.asm) file into List
2. Open `StreamWriter` for output (.hack) file.
3. Loop through `List<string>` modify the string and write into file.

Code Example:

```
 List<string> lstInput = new List<string>();     

 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"input.asm"))
 {
    string sLine = string.Empty;
    //read one line at a time
    while ((sLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        lstInput.Add(sLine);
    }
 }

 using (StreamWriter writer =  new StreamWriter(@"output.hack"))
 {
       foreach(string sFullLine in lstInput)
       {
           string sNumber = sFullLine;
           //remove leading @ sign
           if(sFullLine.StartsWith("@"))               
              sNumber = sFullLine.Substring(1);

           int iNumber;
           if(int.TryParse(sNumber, out iNumber))
           {    
              writer.WriteLine(IntToBinaryString(iNumber));
           }
       }
 }


 public string IntToBinaryString(int number)
 {
     const int mask = 1;
     var binary = string.Empty;
     while(number > 0)
     {
         // Logical AND the number and prepend it to the result string
         binary = (number & 1) + binary;
         number = number >> 1;
     }
     return binary;
 }
```

Reference: [IntToBinaryString](http://davidzych.com/2013/12/06/converting-an-int-to-a-binary-string-in-c) method.

**NOTE**: Int to Binary String method mentioned in the answer of @TheDutchMan is better choice.

Comment: Plus one for the using keyword.